# How can I create a multiple loop in R?

Tags: r, loops

I am working with a database of daily deaths of a country, so I need to create a database that contains the aggregated data of daily deaths by day, month and state. My database (def_2020) is something  like this:

```
|--------------|------------|-------|
|     State    |     Month  |  Day  |
|--------------|------------|-------|
|     state1   |     jan    |   1   |
|--------------|------------|-------| 
|     state1   |     jan    |   1   |
|--------------|------------|-------|
|       .      |      .     |   .   |
|--------------|------------|-------|
|       .      |      .     |   .   |
|--------------|------------|-------| 
|     state2   |      dic   |   4   |
|--------------|------------|-------|
```

I have 24 states (100.000 obs), of diferent days and months of death. I need to get something like this:

```
|--------------|------------|-------|-------|
|     State    |     Month  |  Day  | Deaths|
|--------------|------------|-------|-------|
|     state1   |    jan     |   1   |   25  |
|--------------|------------|-------|-------| 
|     state1   |    jan     |   2   |   35  |
|--------------|------------|-------|-------|
|       .      |      .     |   .   |       |
|--------------|------------|-------|-------|
|       .      |      .     |   .   |       |
|--------------|------------|-------|-------|
|     state2   |      dic   |   4   |       |
|--------------|------------|-------|-------|
```

I am new to R, so I create loop like this:

```
day <- c(1:31)
death_state1 <- NULL
  
for (i in day) {
    death_state_1[i] <- sum(with(def2020 %>% filter(State == "state1", Month =="jan"), Day == i))
}
```

But I need to optimize this loop to get a dataframe by month (columns), days (rows) and states (also rows). Help me please, I'm still new with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using a mixture of base R and `dplyr` syntax (the pipe `%>%` and `filter` are exports from the `dplyr` package.)

`dplyr` has its own syntax for grouped operations that allows you to avoid defining explicit loops. You use `group_by()` to group your data and `summarize()` to define variables containing the results of dimension-reducing functions like `mean()`, `min()`, `n()`, etc.

```
def_2020 %>%
  group_by(State, Month, Day) %>%
  summarize(Deaths = n())
```

Comment: I definitely have a lot to learn, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

With `base R`, we can use `aggregate`

```
aggregate(Deaths ~ ., transform(def_2020, Deaths = 1), FUN = sum)
```